# Check if window from loaded assembly is open

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, .net-assembly

I have the below code that is executed on a button click to open a window from another application.exe

```
gAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(JLDBConnection.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultString + @"\JLRetailTerminal.exe");
Type typ = gAssembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(s => s.Name == "RetailWindow").FirstOrDefault();
typ.GetMethod("Show").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(typ), null);
```

`gAssembly` is a global variable.
How can I check if the "RetailWindow" is already opened and do not open another window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the only one creating it? If so, you can store the window instance and check the IsVisible:

I.e.:

```
g_wnd = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

if (!g_wnd.IsVisible)
{
}
```

Comment: Worked magically, had to extend to check if the window has been closed and truly needs to be reopened.

Answer (score -1):

Full Solution.

```
    var gAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(JLDBConnection.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultString + @"\JLRetailTerminal.exe");
    Type typ = gAssembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(s => s.Name == "RetailWindow").FirstOrDefault();
    //if extend sale is set prevent multiple windows
    if (gWindow == null)
    {//show if window has never been opened
          gWindow = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
          gWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {//window has been opened
          var windows = Application.Current.Windows; //get all opened windows in applications                                        
          if (!windows.OfType<Window>().Contains(gWindow) || !(JLDBConnection.Properties.Settings.Default.ExtendSale == "Yes"))
          {   //if window has been closed   or not multiple sale database                                                                                
                gWindow = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
                gWindow.Show();
          }
     }
```